# I'll take you up on your/that job offer if (-----------)

Tags: expressions, synonyms, collocations

Looking for a natural English phrasing, I am stuck at what I should put in the blank below. I'm pretty sure I heard the expression before but I can't seem to remember it, and I racked my brains hard enough to no avail.

> I'll take you up on your/that job offer if (-----------).

- it's still on
- it still holds
- it still stands
- it's still standing
- it's still on the table

Or is it something else I do not know.

Comment: All of them sound reasonable to this US English speaker.  Maybe "if it's still standing" is the least natural-sounding - we usually just say *the offer stands*, not *the offer is standing* - but that's about it.

Comment: It's immediate which might qualify for standing, but I felt stands is better; a conflict between logic and gut feeling! Thanks stangdon. But, wow, did not expect all to be okay!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*it still stands* sounds the best. *it is still available* is another alternative (if you are not sure if they filled the job)